# Swift 5.5 Await/Async Parallelism for large file upload

Tags: swift5

I have a function that reads in chunks of a file and then uploads the chunks to S3 in a multipart upload. I have coded the functions in AF await / async.

I want to paralellize the upload to make it faster. The sequntial function that works but is slow looks like this:

```swift
func uploadMultiPart(file: URL) async throws {
        
        let size = try self.getFileSize(file: file)
        let parts = try self.numberParts(file: file)
        var completedMultipartUpload = [CompletedPart]()
        
        let uploadID = try await self.initiateMultiPartUpload(key: file.lastPathComponent)
        
        let handle = try FileHandle(forReadingFrom: file)
        
        for i in (1...parts) {
            debugPrint("Start Offset: \(try handle.offset())")
            var data: Data = Data()

            if i == parts {
                data = handle.readDataToEndOfFile()
            } else {
                data = handle.readData(ofLength: Int(self.partSize))
            }
            
            debugPrint("End Offset: \(try handle.offset())")
            
            let etag = try await self.uploadPart(file: file, uploadID: uploadID, part: Int(i), data: data, totalSize: size)
            let completedPart = CompletedPart(ETag: etag, PartNumber: Int32(i))
            
            completedMultipartUpload.append(completedPart)
        }
        try await self.completeMultipartUpload(completedUpload: completedMultipartUpload, uploadID: uploadID, key: file.lastPathComponent)
    }
```

I looked into using `withThrowingTaskGroup` and `group.addTask { some async task}` but this cause large files to spawn thousands of uploads instead of say 5 or 6 at a time. Like this:

```swift
    func testMultiPart(file: URL) async throws {
        let size = try self.getFileSize(file: file)
        let parts = try self.numberParts(file: file)
        var completedMultipartUpload = [CompletedPart]()
        
        let uploadID = try await self.initiateMultiPartUpload(key: file.lastPathComponent)
        
        try await withThrowingTaskGroup(of: CompletedPart.self) { group in
            
            for i in (1...parts) {
                
                group.addTask() {
                    debugPrint("Starting Part: \(i)")
                    let handle = try FileHandle(forReadingFrom: file)
                    
                    try handle.seek(toOffset: UInt64(i-1) * UInt64(self.partSize))
                    
                    var data: Data = Data()

                    if i == parts {
                        data = handle.readDataToEndOfFile()
                    } else {
                        data = handle.readData(ofLength: Int(self.partSize))
                    }
                    
                    let etag = try await self.uploadPart(file: file, uploadID: uploadID, part: Int(i), data: data, totalSize: size)
                    let completedPart = CompletedPart(ETag: etag, PartNumber: Int32(i))
                    
                    
                    return completedPart
                }
            }
            for try await completedPart in group {
                completedMultipartUpload.append(completedPart)
            }
        }
        completedMultipartUpload.sort { $0.PartNumber < $1.PartNumber }
        try await self.completeMultipartUpload(completedUpload: completedMultipartUpload, uploadID: uploadID, key: file.lastPathComponent)
    }
```

How can I do some number of parallel uploads with await/async then continue once those have finished?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this was to use a DispatchSemaphore:

```swift
func testMultiPart(file: URL) async throws {
    let size = try self.getFileSize(file: file)
    let parts = try self.numberParts(file: file)
    var completedMultipartUpload = [CompletedPart]()
    
    let uploadID = try await self.initiateMultiPartUpload(key: file.lastPathComponent)
    
    try await withThrowingTaskGroup(of: CompletedPart.self) { group in
        let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 5)
        
        for i in (1...parts) {
            semaphore.wait()
            group.addTask() {
                debugPrint("Starting Part: \(i)")
                let handle = try FileHandle(forReadingFrom: file)
                
                try handle.seek(toOffset: UInt64(i-1) * UInt64(self.partSize))
                
                var data: Data = Data()

                if i == parts {
                    data = handle.readDataToEndOfFile()
                } else {
                    data = handle.readData(ofLength: Int(self.partSize))
                }
                
                let etag = try await self.uploadPart(file: file, uploadID: uploadID, part: Int(i), data: data, totalSize: size)
                let completedPart = CompletedPart(ETag: etag, PartNumber: Int32(i))
                
                semaphore.signal()
                try handle.close()
                debugPrint("Finished Part: \(i)")
                return completedPart
            }
        }
        for try await completedPart in group {
            completedMultipartUpload.append(completedPart)
        }
    }
    completedMultipartUpload.sort { $0.PartNumber < $1.PartNumber }
    try await self.completeMultipartUpload(completedUpload: completedMultipartUpload, uploadID: uploadID, key: file.lastPathComponent)
    self.fractionCompleted = 1.0
}
```